# R. Add color to a group of points in R plot

Tags: r, plot, points

I made a plot with 1000000 points using plot() and the data from object z = data.frame(x,y). I have a separate data frame with a column of 1000 rows (values) df$v. All elements from df$v intersect with z[,"x"].

I want to plot all these values (points) with a different color, let's say green. I know how to do it one by one, e.g. for the value 582251 from df$v:

```
plot(z$x, z$y,.....)

points(z[z[,"x"]==582251,],col="green", pch=19, cex=0.3)
```

Is there any way to do it for the whole df$v using points()?

Comment: I think that you just want `points(z[df$v,],col="green", pch=19, cex=0.3)`

Comment: Thanks very much @G5W, it works now with your edited solution !

Answer (score 1):

I would create another vector just for colors. This can be added to your existing data.frame `z` using `z = cbind(z, 'col'='black')`. This will produce a new column in `z`. Then you replace the black with green for desired points using `z$col[z$x %in% df$v] = 'green'`. Then run the following command

`plot(z$x, z$y, col = z$col)`